# Debugging not working in Firefox - Firebug

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, firebug

I'm trying to debug an extJS based JavaScript form in Firefox 3.0.8, with Firebug, but none of my debugging statements are working.  `console.log` produces the error `console is not defined` in the console.  The `debugger` statement just doesn't work.

Comment: Did you activate the Firebug console for the domain you are working on ?

Comment: Yes, it's localhost, and I deactivated and reactivated and still nothing.  I'm going to re-install Firebug in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that you have another Firefox extension installed which messes up for Firebug's console. I installed "HttpWatch Basic" for instance and it broke console.log() .. Disabled HttpWatch and everything was fine again.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Firefox 2.x ?

Call loadFirebugConsole() to load the logger explicitly before you try to log to it.

Comment: I'm using FF 3.0.8, and that call gives me an 'undefined error' as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try window.console.log(). Works in IE, may work FF3 in your case.